# Does a GraphQL Operation Name Ever Change Query Behavior?

Tags: graphql

I'm super new to GraphQL.  I'm still getting my bearings around basic concepts and language.  I may say something that's massively wrong in asking my question -- if I do this, I'd appreciate a correction.

Short Question: Does an operation's name have any impact on the behavior of a query?

That is, it's my understanding that, given a GraphQL query that looks like this

```
query SomeQueryName {
    flower {
        name
        petal_number
    }
}
```

That `query` is the operation type, and `SomeQueryName` is the operation name.

Are these names ever used while resolving a query? Or are they strictly something that client programmers can include when writing a query in order to help them organize their own code?  Or some other thing I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation's name is not relevant to resolving the fields inside the operation. **However**, it is relevant when multiple operation definitions exist within a single GraphQL document. [From the spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Executing-Requests):

> To execute a request, the executor must have a parsed Document and a selected operation name to run if the document defines multiple operations, otherwise the document is expected to only contain a single operation.

In other words, your request could include a document like this:

```
query Query1 {
  someField
}

query Query2 {
  someOtherField
}
```

When multiple named operations exist, the client must also specify an `operationName` parameter (in addition to `query` and `variables`). By doing so tells the GraphQL service to execute that specific operation and ignore all others. Sending multiple operations without specifying an `operationName` -- or including more than one unnamed operation will cause the request to fail.

Outside the above, as @jo_va mentioned, the only other purpose of providing an operation name is for debugging or for use by the client. For example, `apollo-link-watched-mutation` uses operation names to address a common caching issue with the Apollo client.

Answer (score 4):

The query name doesn't have any meaning for the server. It is not used while resolving the query, only the content of the query is used. So your example is equivalent to this:

```
query {
    flower {
        name
        petal_number
    }
}
```

The name is only used by the GraphQL client on the frontend or for debugging purposes.